# Flutter - what is the difference between enabledBorder and Border

Tags: flutter, dart

I was making a search bar in flutter and couldn't seem to figure out the difference between enabledBorder and border in the OutlineInputBorder widget.
I also want different border colors when I tap on the search bar and when I come out of it.
for example, if I set the border's color to green and the enabledBorder's color to red it just shows red at all times.

Comment: im not a flutter dev but it enabledBorder might be exclusive for when the widget is not grayed out

Comment: thought so too but when I change its color property it changes the color when it's both greyed out and active

Answer (score 1):

**According to the flutter docs,**

> border → InputBorder The shape of the border to draw around the
> decoration's container.

> enabledBorder → InputBorder The border to display when the
> InputDecorator is enabled and is not showing an error

The enabledBorder is the specific border that will be displayed when the TextField is enabled or in simply words when you click on the TextField.

Answer (score 0):

This gives a border to the container when the container is not active/enabled or focused and color is default:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),                     
  border: OutlineInputBorder( 
// in here
 ),
```

This gives the containers color-> yellow, shape of curved side which the user see when the page is visited :

```
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder( 
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow, width: 2.0),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
  ),
```

When the user tap to input into the container -> this give container color->green, boundary, shape of sides specific to the focused container :

```
  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 3.0),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(32.0)),
  ),
);
```